# NetBeans only loading 50% when I try to run code?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am very new to Java. I am attempting to write a simple code that prints out calories consumed based on number of cookies eaten. Every time I try to run the code it simply loads to 50% then stops.

This is what I have so far:

```
package com.mycompany.assignment2;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cookie {
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  int cookiesEaten;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("How many cookies did you eat? ");
  cookiesEaten = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("\n\n\n\tYou ate " + cookiesEaten + " cookies");
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you copied all of your code, there is a syntax error since you're missing a closing bracket `}` at the end

Comment: There is an Syntax error in your code. Add the last `}`. And what do you mean by 50%?

Comment: If the syntax error mentioned already does not apply, what do you mean by 'Every time I try to run the code it simply loads to 50% then stops'?

Comment: I missed a bracket when I copied it, I edited my post to include it so thank you. When I press "Run Project in Netbeans a loading bar pops up at the bottom, the bar will fill to 50% then stop loading.

Comment: @Ellen only thing we can suggest with this amout of detail given is: 1) restart computer, 2) uninstall and reinstall this IDE, and 3) choose a different IDE

Comment: @Samathingamajig O/T, but please don't use the phrase _"...only thing **we** can suggest..."_ to imply some general consensus for your suggestions. You are the only person involved in making that comment, and there is no _"we"_. I certainly wouldn't agree with you that _"choose a different IDE"_ is a constructive or useful suggestion.